# ClassPathNotFound error at the beginning of install?

Tags: android

I keep getting this error at the beginning of install. Once its installed the application then works.

Here is the error if anyone is familiar with it please let me know.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fttech.books-1.apk]
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.fttech.books"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="2.0"> 
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion ="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/bookicon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".main"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".creat"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".view" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".shopFor" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".DbAdapter"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Lookup" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".myAdmob"/>
    </application>

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" 
      android:smallScreens="true"   
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true" 
      android:xlargeScreens="true" 
      android:anyDensity="true"  />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show off your Android Manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error and your manifest it seams that the system doesn't know the `com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver`-Receiver.

I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/cf3c87794dbfe3a6/5e37c95e51a051c5?lnk=raot), which treats the same error.

Comment: Okay cool! I took the snippet out and everything works like a charm.